# Is it possible to replicate SQL Azure database to another Azure database?

Tags: sql, azure-sql-database, database-replication

Is it possible to replicate SQL Azure database to another Azure database?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

Azure offers Georeplication,which you can use to replicate your db to some other region..

This is what docs say:[Overview: SQL Database Active Geo-Replication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-geo-replication-overview)

> The Active Geo-Replication feature implements a mechanism to provide database redundancy within the same Microsoft Azure region or in different regions (geo-redundancy).
>
> Active Geo-Replication asynchronously replicates committed transactions from a database to up to four copies of the database on different servers, using read committed snapshot isolation (RCSI) for isolation

you also can use secondary database for read operations

> An application can access a secondary database for read-only operations using the same or different security principals used for accessing the primary database. The secondary databases operate in snapshot isolation mode to ensure replication of the updates of the primary (log replay) is not delayed by queries executed on the secondary.

Comment: I need something like transactional replication but I found out that it is not supported. Related article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-paas-vs-sql-server-iaas
It seems azure DB supports SQL Server transactional replication only as a subscriber to replicate data. 

Thanks for the answer!